# Databricks scala dbfs cache

Tags: scala, caching, databricks, azure-databricks

I have text files stored in Azure Databricks DBFS/FileStore location.
The files are getting cached after I read then using the below command as when I reupload the modified .txt file and reread, I can see only the old file data.

```scala
contents = fromFile(filepath).getLines.mkString("\n");
```

How can I clear the dbfs session cache in my notebook or use a command/function not to cache the files in dbfs filestore?

Comment: Can you try using `spark.catalog.clearCache()` to clear the cache? let me know if it works.

Comment: Did you re-execute line after uploading file?

Answer (score 0):

- As far as I know, there is no specific cache for DBFS. The spark clusters have cache and to clear this, you can use the following command.

```
spark.catalog.clearCache()
```

- However, when you are reading a text file using the command given, it is returning data as expected. When you modify the text file and re-upload it, DBFS renames the file to avoid file name duplication. Refer to the following image.

[image]

- So, make sure to delete the old file and then upload the modified .txt file or update the filePath variable value to point to the file you want to read.